# Access This Class using Each Function

Tags: jquery, class, this, each, parent

I have some code that increments each letter of a given word starting from A until reaching the destination letter. You can see the example in the code snippet below. The code works when I target a single div id but I want to make it so it will apply this incrementing text effect to every block of text with the "block" class assigned to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("ready!");

  $('.block').each(function() {

    function Letter(table, letter, duration) {
      this.table = table;
      this.letter = letter;
      this.current = 0;
      this.delay = duration / tbl.indexOf(letter); // ms
      this.time = Date.now();
      this.done = false;
    }
    Letter.prototype.update = function() {
      if (this.done) return;
      var time = Date.now();
      if (time - this.time >= this.delay) {
        this.time = time;
        if (this.letter === this.table[this.current] || this.current === this.table.length) {
          this.done = true;
        } else {
          this.current++;
        }
      }
    };

    var word = $(this).html();
    console.log('Word: ' + word);

    var tbl = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var letters = [];
    word.toUpperCase().split("").forEach(function(l) {
      letters.push(new Letter(tbl, l, 2500))
      console.log(l);
    });

    (function loop() {
      var txt = "",
        isDone = true;
      letters.forEach(function(l) {
        l.update();
        if (!l.done) isDone = false;
        txt += l.table[l.current];
      });

      // output txt
      //$("div#d").html(txt);
      $(this).parent('.block').html(txt);

      if (!isDone) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      else { /* done */ }
    })();

  });

});
```

I'm trying to output the incrementing effect onto each text bit with the "block" class assigned to it:

```
$(this).parent('.block').html(txt);
```

I am trying to target each "block" class with the above line of code but it is not working. How can I do this?

Notice with this line the "Word" being incremented is whatever falls inside the "block" tag:

```
var word = $(this).html();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("ready!");

  $('.block').each(function() {

    function Letter(table, letter, duration) {
      this.table = table;
      this.letter = letter;
      this.current = 0;
      this.delay = duration / tbl.indexOf(letter); // ms
      this.time = Date.now();
      this.done = false;
    }
    Letter.prototype.update = function() {
      if (this.done) return;
      var time = Date.now();
      if (time - this.time >= this.delay) {
        this.time = time;
        if (this.letter === this.table[this.current] ||
          this.current === this.table.length) {
          this.done = true;
        } else {
          this.current++;
        }
      }
    };

    var word = $(this).html();
    console.log('Word: ' + word);

    var tbl = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var letters = [];
    word.toUpperCase().split("").forEach(function(l) {
      letters.push(new Letter(tbl, l, 2500))
      console.log(l);
    });

    (function loop() {
      var txt = "",
        isDone = true;
      letters.forEach(function(l) {
        l.update();
        if (!l.done) isDone = false;
        txt += l.table[l.current];
      });

      // output txt
      //d.innerHTML = txt;
      $("div#d").html(txt);

      if (!isDone) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      else { /* done */ }
    })();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=d></div>

<div id="other_spans">
  <span class="block">First</span>
  <span class="block">Second</span>
  <span class="block">Third</span>
```

Comment: Where should result be returned? To same `#d` element?

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but couldn't the `Letter()` constructor and the `update()` method be declared before the `.each()` loop? They're not really part of the loop logic. Also, I hope you don't mind, but I edited your question just to fix the code's indenting (no changes to the actual code itself) because as it was it was hard to see where each block ended.

Comment: @guest271314 each result is returned the corresponding ".block" class element. In other words, in the above example "First" "Second" and "Third" would all display the incrementing effect because they have the "block" span around them

Comment: So your desired behaviour is that the word "First" should be animated *in place* in its span, independent of the word "Second" that would be animated in place in *its* span, etc.? And then the div with the id "d" wouldn't be needed at all? And when the whole thing is finished should they just display their original words again, or...?

Comment: @nnnnn yes that is exactly right. Each "word" value to increment comes from the text inside the "block" span. The incrementing takes place inside the span for each letter, starting from A, and then the end result is that the original word shows.

Comment: Oh right. Looks [prettier](https://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/v23jm5Lt/) if you include lowercase letters in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `Letter` function and `tbl` variable outside of `.each()` to prevent redefining function, variable at each iteration of elements; create a reference to `$(this)` current element, use reference inside of `loop`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("ready!");

  var tbl = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  function Letter(table, letter, duration) {
    this.table = table;
    this.letter = letter;
    this.current = 0;
    this.delay = duration / tbl.indexOf(letter); // ms
    this.time = Date.now();
    this.done = false;
  }
  
  Letter.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.done) return;
    var time = Date.now();
    if (time - this.time >= this.delay) {
      this.time = time;
      if (this.letter === this.table[this.current] 
          || this.current === this.table.length) {
        this.done = true;
      } else {
        this.current++;
      }
    }
  };

  $(".block").each(function() {
    // store reference to current `this` element
    var elem = $(this);
    var word = elem.html();
    console.log("Word: " + word);
    var letters = [];

    word.toUpperCase().split("")
    .forEach(function(l) {
      letters.push(new Letter(tbl, l, 2500))
      console.log(l);
    });

    (function loop() {
      var txt = "",
        isDone = true;
      letters.forEach(function(l) {
        l.update();
        if (!l.done) isDone = false;
        txt += l.table[l.current];
      });
      // `elem` : `this` element at `.each()` iteration
      elem.html(txt);

      if (!isDone) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      else { /* done */ }
    })();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="d"></div>

<div id="other_spans">
  <span class="block">First</span>
  <span class="block">Second</span>
  <span class="block">Third</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the this inside IIFE is the window object. Keep a reference of the element with block class and use it inside the IIFE. Like below -

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("ready!");
    var tbl = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    function Letter(table, letter, duration) {
        this.table = table;
        this.letter = letter;
        this.current = 0;
        this.delay = duration / tbl.indexOf(letter); // ms
        this.time = Date.now();
        this.done = false;
    }
    Letter.prototype.update = function() {
        if (this.done) return;
        var time = Date.now();
        if (time - this.time >= this.delay) {
            this.time = time;
            if (this.letter === this.table[this.current] || this.current === this.table.length) {
                this.done = true;
            } else {
                this.current++;
            }
        }
    };


    $('.block').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        var word = $(this).html();
        console.log('Word: ' + word);


        var letters = [];
        word.toUpperCase().split("").forEach(function(l) {
            letters.push(new Letter(tbl, l, 2500))
            console.log(l);
        });

        (function loop() {
            var txt = "",
                isDone = true;
            letters.forEach(function(l) {
                l.update();
                if (!l.done) isDone = false;
                txt += l.table[l.current];
            });

            // output txt
            //$("div#d").html(txt);
            $this.html(txt);

            if (!isDone) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            else { /* done */ }
        })();

    });
});
```

Here's a link to the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/tg9hpk4a/

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code with your changes but it still does not output anything

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to working fiddle, please check.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa Why re-define `Letter` function and `tbl` variable at each iteration of `.each()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, you are right ... I missed that part, updated the code now. Thanks.